# Problem about the relationship of 2 periodic functions

Tags: periodic-functions

If $f,\varphi$ are two even periodic functions with $T=2$. Suppose
$$f(x) = x(2-x),\quad \varphi(x) = x,\quad x\in [0,1]$$
prove that:
$$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\varphi(2^nx),\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}.$$
I wonder if I need to make use of the fourier expansion of $f$ and $\varphi$, can anyone offer me some help?

Comment: Have you verified that they are periodic and even?

Comment: The expression given above is only in $[0,1]$, and that's enough to uniquely determine $f$ and $\varphi$ since they are even and periodic.

Comment: Do you mean f(x)=f(x+2n) for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, and the respective for the second function?

Comment: Yes. The 2 functions are therefore determined.

Comment: It seems that I should make use of the fourier expansion.

Comment: Have you tried?